# Как использовать функцию String.format()?

Tags: java, android

Как можно переписать приведенный код ниже с помощью функции `String.format()`?

```
String s = getReference().getString(R.string.pre_text_main)
      + " " + str + " " + getReference().getString(R.string.post_text_main);

getReference().endText.setText(s);
```

Comment: Ваш код вполне оптимален, не нужно его менять.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первый вариант хороший, но есть еще один: можно доставать строки сразу с параметром для форматирования. Например, твой строковый ресурс:

```
<string name="text_main">Какой-то пре-текст %s какой-то пост-текс</string>
```

Затем ты можешь достать в коде этот строковый ресурс, сразу поставив туда вместо **%s** нужное слово. Пример кода:

```
getString(R.string.text_main, str)
```

где, **str** то что встанет в параметр.

Comment: спасибо большое!!! вы очень помогли!!!

Comment: проблема решена!!!

Answer (score 3):

`String.format()` принимает первым аргументом формат, описание которого приведено [в классе `Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

В Вашем случае, необходимо в формате применить флаг `s`, который вызывает `arg.toString()`

```
String prefix = getReference().getString(R.string.pre_text_main);    
String suffix = getReference().getString(R.string.post_text_main);

getReference().endText.setText(String.format("%s %s %s", prefix, str, suffix));
```

Comment: спасибо большое!!! вы очень помогли!!!